# Insert a record which is returned from different query?

Tags: sqlite

I want to get ID from "Stores" corresponding to passed StoreName.

```
 Select ID from Stores WHERE Name='Megamart'
```

Now I want it this id to insert in a table. 
I did this:

```
INSERT INTO NetOrderID ( StoreID, SalesManID) VALUES ( " Select ID from Stores WHERE Name='Megamart'" , 1)
```

But as it turns out this doesn't work. Help!

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO NetOrderID ( StoreID, SalesManID) 
Select ID, 1 from Stores WHERE Name='Megamart'
```

Comment: Yes thats working \m/ 
But I dont understand, 1 is supposed to be SalesmanId, How do you form this query, like what is the structure

Comment: `1` will be the `SalesManID`. The select will get `ID` from the `Stores` table and insert it as `StoreID` and takes the `1` and inserts it in `SalesManID`.

Comment: You can only use the `values ...` part if don't have to select anything.